# How to implement SSO between 2 web apps on the same domain

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, session-cookies

I have two completely separate web apps:

www.example.com (node.js)

www.example.com/shop (java)

Users sign in to www.example.com, and when they go to /shop, I want that web app to be able to identify the user without them needing to sign in again.

I have an OAuth2 public api, and am using cookies to manage the users' session within the web app.  I'm trying to figure out the best way to implement SSO between these two web apps.

The /shop web app can read the cookie, but doesn't have access to the actual session store.  The /shop app needs to make api calls anyway, so if I can use OAuth2 to implement SSO, that seems like it would be ideal.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two are orthogonal. SSO is simply credential sharing.

Since you already have the cookie, that's shared between them and that's fine to let them in to both apps. Simply encode Interesting Information that you want to share between them in the cookie (notably user id, and perhaps any relevant roles).

Ideally what you would do is use the shared cookie for authentication, then when your /shop web app starts its OWN session (i.e. the shared cookie is NOT the same as your session cookie), you stand up an internal security context of some kind. Ostensibly you'll pull the user id off of the cookie and then look that up in your common user store to get the appropriate information.

This will work for 99% of use cases.

So your workflow would be, when the user hits your /shop app.

- Check for Shared cookie
- If it doesn't exist, redirect them to the main app to log in
- If it does exists, check if you have a valid session for this instance started
- If not, then start a session, and look up user information based on ID in the cookie (user names, roles, preferences). These you can store in the session
- Go shopping

Log out is simply destroying the shared cookie.

- Check for shared cookie.
- If no shared cookie, check for session
- If a session exists, destroy it

Oh, don't forget to sign your Shared cookie once they get logged in.

There's no reason to involve OAuth in this. Way overcomplicates it.